# using two separate sets of time series data to correlate against other datasets

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two sets of time series data that I want to correlate against my heart rate.

Currently, the two sets look a bit like this,

I've removed user_id as a column for obvious reasons :P

Scheduled,

```
startdate   user_id substance   scheduledtimes  enddate duration    planneddose used
2021-12-16  13f13f18093hjasodnias09fjaspasofj   Ritalin LA  [8.0]   2021-12-16  8   10  True
2022-01-03  1239nason98hwe9123e9nda0s8n01   Elvanse [9.0]   2022-02-26  12  70  False
2021-11-07  BAPIASNDNO1093jdfnasofin103fn   Test substance2 [10.0, 12.0, 16.0]  2020-01-09  5   10  False
2021-11-16  BAPIASNDNO1093jdfnasofin103fn   some sub    [4.0]   2021-11-07  123 1231    True
2021-11-02  BAPIASNDNO1093jdfnasofin103fn   asd [2.0, 4.0]  2021-11-07  123 123 False
```

Actual,

```
input   dose    device  duration    timestamp   id  user_id
Dexamphetamine  10  1   5   2022-01-16 14:25:36.812465+00:00    3   13f13f18093hjasodnias09fjaspasofj
Dexamphetamine  10  1   5   2022-01-19 13:37:57.334686+00:00    4   13f13f18093hjasodnias09fjaspasofj
Dexamphetamine  10  1   5   2022-01-19 13:41:56.068653+00:00    5   13f13f18093hjasodnias09fjaspasofj
Dexamphetamine  10  1   5   2022-01-19 20:57:56.228226+00:00    7   BAPIASNDNO1093jdfnasofin103fn
Morphin 50  1   5   2022-01-19 21:26:06.218088+00:00    11  BAPIASNDNO1093jdfnasofin103fn
```

I want to take my sentiment data

```
created id  user_id sentiment   magnitude
2020-12-01 04:18:29 9269    12d9812dj918h2dhasdihLHSALOSADH 1   1
2020-12-01 04:58:07 9270    12d9812dj918h2dhasdihLHSALOSADH 1   1
2020-12-01 04:58:09 9271    12d9812dj918h2dhasdihLHSALOSADH 1   1
2020-12-01 04:58:13 9272    12d9812dj918h2dhasdihLHSALOSADH 1   1
2020-12-01 04:58:20 9273    12d9812dj918h2dhasdihLHSALOSADH 1   1
2020-12-01 04:58:22 9274    12d9812dj918h2dhasdihLHSALOSADH 1   1
2020-12-01 05:00:00 9275    12d9812dj918h2dhasdihLHSALOSADH 0.4 1
2020-12-01 05:00:06 9276    12d9812dj918h2dhasdihLHSALOSADH -1  1
2020-12-01 05:00:09 9277    12d9812dj918h2dhasdihLHSALOSADH -0.8    1
2020-12-01 05:00:20 9278    12d9812dj918h2dhasdihLHSALOSADH -1  1
2020-12-01 05:00:25 9279    12d9812dj918h2dhasdihLHSALOSADH -1  1
2020-12-01 05:00:39 9280    12d9812dj918h2dhasdihLHSALOSADH -1  1
2020-12-01 05:00:44 9281    12d9812dj918h2dhasdihLHSALOSADH -1  1
2020-12-01 05:00:52 9282    12d9812dj918h2dhasdihLHSALOSADH -1  1
2020-12-01 05:00:58 9283    12d9812dj918h2dhasdihLHSALOSADH -1  1
2020-12-01 05:01:10 9284    12d9812dj918h2dhasdihLHSALOSADH -1  1
2020-12-01 05:01:13 9285    12d9812dj918h2dhasdihLHSALOSADH -1  1
2020-12-01 05:01:15 9286    12d9812dj918h2dhasdihLHSALOSADH -1  1
2020-12-01 05:01:19 9287    12d9812dj918h2dhasdihLHSALOSADH -1  1
2020-12-01 05:01:25 9288    12d9812dj918h2dhasdihLHSALOSADH -1  1
```

These are the functions I used for test data,

```
def get_stats(group):
    diff = group.astype(int).abs().diff()

    return {'min': group.min(), 'max': group.max(),\
            'mean': group.mean(),'median': group.median(),\
           'var': group.var(),'std': group.std()}


def timeFilter(df):
    df_Meds = df.reset_index()

    start_date = '03-01-2020'
    end_date = '12-30-2021'
    mask = (df_Meds['created'] > start_date) & (df_Meds['created'] <= end_date)

    df = df_Meds.loc[mask]
    return df
```

Passing in just one substance with one set of times,like this

```
scheduled_substance_user=scheduled_substance_df[scheduled_substance_df.user_id =="xxx"]
dexamphet_scheduled = scheduled_substance_user[scheduled_substance_user.substance =="Dexamphetamine"]
# dexamphet_scheduled.iloc[0]

dexamphet_scheduled.scheduledtimes.iloc[0]
```

returning this,

```
[8.0, 14.0, 18.0]
```

I get something like this,

```
test_df = SubstanceTimingHeartRate(Biometrics,dexamphet_scheduled.scheduledtimes.iloc[0])

test_df[test_df.medication >0]
```

but now I want to label is

1. What the substance is,
2. Use that substances duration
3. If it was an actual, or scheduled timestamp.

Example output, but with heart rate, will share with sentiment!
[image]

Appreciate any help with this - python is super complex to me.

Very confused about how best to approach this with these and appreciate any help.

#### Update to code so far,

```
scheduled_substance_user=scheduled_substance_df[scheduled_substance_df.user_id =="xxxx"]

n=0
sentiment_scheduled=pd.DataFrame()
for x in scheduled_substance_user.substance.unique():
    drug_scheduled = scheduled_substance_user[scheduled_substance_user.substance ==x]
    # print("get here?")
    print("\tdrug",x,drug_scheduled.substance.unique())
    if n<1:

        n=n+1

        # print("get here?")

        sentiment_scheduled=SubstanceTimingSentiment(Emotions,drug_scheduled.scheduledtimes.iloc[0],drug_scheduled.duration.iloc[0],x,drug_scheduled.index[0],drug_scheduled.enddate.iloc[0])
        print("\t Unique substances",sentiment_scheduled.substance.unique())
       

    else:
    # print("n>=1?")
        # drug_scheduled = scheduled_substance_user[scheduled_substance_user.substance ==x]


        sentiment_scheduled.append(SubstanceTimingSentiment(Emotions,drug_scheduled.scheduledtimes.iloc[0],drug_scheduled.duration.iloc[0],x,drug_scheduled.index[0],drug_scheduled.enddate.iloc[0]), ignore_index=True)
        print("\t Unique substances in dataframe",sentiment_scheduled.substance.unique())
```

and the function,

```
def SubstanceTimingSentiment(emo_d,substance_timing,duration,substance_name,startdate,enddate):
    print("call this function?")
    start_date=pd.to_datetime(startdate)
    end_date=pd.to_datetime(enddate)
    # convert times to datetime
    med_times = pd.to_datetime(substance_timing)
    # df.created = pd.to_datetime(df.created)
    df = emo_d.reset_index()

    # drop rows that are empty except for column 0 (i.e., except for df.created)
    # df.dropna(subset=df.columns[1:], inplace=True)

    # convert times to datetime i.e., ['09:00:00', '12:00:00', '15:00:00']
    df.created = pd.to_datetime(df.created)
    df = df[(df.created > start_date) & (df.created < end_date)]
    print("\tstart and end times:",startdate,enddate)

    taken = pd.to_datetime(substance_timing)

    # generate time arrays
    duration = int(duration) # hours
    active = np.array([(taken + pd.Timedelta(f'{h}H')).time for h in range(duration)]).ravel()
    after = (taken + pd.Timedelta(f'{duration}H')).time

    # define boolean masks by label
    conditions = {
        1: df.created.dt.floor('H').dt.time.isin(active),
        2: df.created.dt.floor('H').dt.time.isin(after),
    }

    # create medication column with np.select()
    df['medication'] = np.select(conditions.values(), conditions.keys(), default=0)
    df['substance'] = substance_name
    df = df[['created', 
        'sentiment', 'magnitude','substance','medication']].set_index('created')
    return df
```

Currently when it is looping through, it isn't appending the new dataframe from the function, and just keeping the first substance in place :/
like this (log)

```
drug Dexamphetamine ['Dexamphetamine']
call this function?
    start and end times: 2021-10-29 2021-11-08
     Unique substances ['Dexamphetamine']
    drug Modafinil ['Modafinil']
call this function?
    start and end times: 1996-12-02 2021-11-08
     Unique substances in dataframe ['Dexamphetamine']
    drug Nicotine ['Nicotine']
call this function?
    start and end times: 2022-02-01 2022-02-27
     Unique substances in dataframe ['Dexamphetamine']
    drug L-Theanine ['L-Theanine']
call this function?
    start and end times: 1990-12-26 2022-01-19
     Unique substances in dataframe ['Dexamphetamine']
    drug Ritalin ['Ritalin']
call this function?
    start and end times: 1996-12-02 2022-01-31
     Unique substances in dataframe ['Dexamphetamine']
    drug Vysanth ['Vysanth']
call this function?
    start and end times: 1996-12-02 2021-11-08
     Unique substances in dataframe ['Dexamphetamine']
```

#### Output I'm looking to get,

Essentially, taking the sentiment and magnitude timing, and creating an output  with columns like,

Created Sentiment Magnitude Medication Substance Actual,

Where medication is 0 for false, 1 for true, and 2 for 1 hour after the duration.

Substance is the name of the specific substance.

Actual is boolean for true or false.

Comment: Provide sample data in code form or text. Beyond the usual reminder, the reason for this is to encourage readers to play around with the data to come up with answers for you. It also makes sense overall since it avoids the duplication of effort to reconstruct the test data and ensures that it actually fits your case.

Comment: In the same logic, provide an example of what you are looking for as output. This will ensure that the answers will provide what is desired in your case.

Comment: It seems that there may be more than one individual involved, can you clarify? If so, include dummy IDs in the input and output data.

Comment: I'm defining the term time series as a function of time, e.g. a series of time stamps with the heart rate at that time. Which medication time series are you referring to? Would it be the blood concentration of particular substances, which surges after ingestion, and is then eliminated at a rate dependent on the substance?

Comment: So, this function I've given uses sentiment instead of heart rate for now, but I am also looking at heart rate @PhilipEgger, and want to do exactly what you're saying in regards to PK/PD type outputs.

I'll write up a better idea of sample data above :)

Comment: Put some sample data for sentiment up above! appreciate any help

Comment: The data you wrote is still not very helpful. if you provide the data read and parsed as it seems you have done it, it would be helpful, otherwise others need to read a bad formatted csv and specify the type of the columns for the dates etc.

Comment: Ahhh vs code doesn't let me use to&clipboard without things exploding, I'm unsure of a easier way to generate it as well, any suggestions?

Comment: You can for example use pd.to_csv(..) copy the data as it appears in the csv and parse it correctly for the others using something like: pd.read_csv('example_2.csv', index_col = 0, parse_dates=True) so the dates are read.

Comment: Yeah the issue is I can't copy the data that is in vs code to browser for some reason :/